# How do I propagate errors to grunt-contrib-watch from grunt-contrib-sass?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

My `grunt-contrib-sass` will stop on compilation error with a traceback when I run `grunt sass`, but not when `sass` is triggered via `grunt-contrib-watch`.

```
    sass: {
        development: {
            options: {
                style: 'expanded'
            },
            files: [
                {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= paths.development %>stylesheets/',
                    src: ['*.scss', '*.sass'],
                    dest: '<%= paths.development %>assets/',
                    ext: '.css.liquid'
                },
            ]
        },


    watch: {
        sass: {
            files: [
                '<%= paths.development %>stylesheets/*{.sass,.*scss}'
            ],
            tasks: ['sass:development']  // this swallows errors
        },
```

I can't seem to find any information on how to prevent this from happening in the grunt-contrib-sass or grunt-contrib-watch documentation. There is no error propagation option.
What am I missing?

I have not had this problem on 5+ other previous grunt based projects with similar `watch->sass` setups and am curious what the internet thinks.

Answer (score 0):

Without any error message it cant be hard to determine how to solve your problem. What does `grunt sass -v` tell you?

Also I've had a similar problem in the past, tho I don't recall the actual error message. I solved the problem by using [grunt-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass) instead of `grunt-contrib-sass`.

Comment: I ultimately used grunt-shell with calls to the locally installed sass --watch directly  (which also solved the problem of compiling all sass).